# Using the private key generated by DCAppAttestService

Tags: ios, swift, security, key-attestation

Apple released a way to attest generated key pairs on the iOS 14 beta, named Device Check App Attestation Service ([DCAppAttestService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice)).

I've already successfully generated a key pair like it is [documented by apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573913-generatekey)

```
DCAppAttestService.shared.generateKey { keyId, error in
   guard error == nil else { /* Handle the error. */ }

   // Cache keyId for subsequent operations.
}
```

After this call I get the keyId in form of a string. But now I don't know if I'm missing something obvious or if it just isn't documented: I absolutely can't figure out how to use this key identifier to retrieve a reference to the associated private key.

I know the itself is stored within the Secure Enclave and I can't directly get it. But I should be able to get a reference of it, a SecKey object, which I could use to sign or encrypt data with calls like

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey, self.algorithm, data as CFData, &error) as Data? else {
   /* Something went wrong */
   return
}
```

The DCAppAttestationService itself doesn't provide any methods to interact with the key using the keyId (except the attestKey and generateAssertion methods).
The mentioned attestKey method is also just returning a serverUnavailableError at the moment, as Apple themselves state [in the release notes.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14-beta-release-notes)

Does anybody have experience with this? How can I get a private key reference to effectively use it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to make use of the key-pair. You can create an effective signature with the generateAssertion method.  However this not a signature over your data alone, but a signature over your data (hash) plus some of Apple's data from the attestKey method.  I have communicated in several ways with Apple about this, the answer is to use the generateAssertion method to do what you need.  To be clear: you cannot obtain a reference to the key-pair.